# Angular re-rendering and changeDetector

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular development and am sure using it incorrectly. What I am seeing is that the Angular re-rendering is not happening when expected and is getting triggered by other events.

When I start building a component on a page, it works as expected, but somewhere down the line the re-rendering part becomes flaky.

Here are some examples. These are all on the same SPA (Single Page Application)
(1) I have a mat-table that fetches it's data from the backend using graphql. The table loads correctly. But on rendering (using the `cdkObserveContent` property binding of the table), the code programatically selects the first row in the table and shows details in another companion component in the page. The selection of the first row used to work fine initially, but somewhere along the `dev` process it stopped working. If the user mouses over the table headers, the 1st row would suddenly get selected and the details in the companion component would highlight correctly.

It almost seems like Angular was not re-rendering it automatically and needing a mouseover event on the column headers to re-render. I eventually added a ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() call at the end of the cdkObserveContent handler to get it to work correctly. (2) In the companion component of (1), I have a variable number of expansion panels.

These worked fine in terms of expanding and collapsing initially, but again as the dev process evolved they displayed the same behavior as (1). Clicking on the expansion panel header would no longer cause them to expand or collapse. Following a click elsewhere in the app would cause the click on the expansion header previously, to work to expand/collapse the panel. Even opening/closing the Dev console tab (Ctrl-Shift-I) would cause the re-rendering to happen. Nothing otherwise, for however long I would wait. Invoking ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() to the click handler for the expansion problem fixed this problem too. Don't know how or why, but it did.

(3) Currently I am dealing with this issue that I have not solved. In the companion component in (2), I have a button to launch a mat-dialog. Again, through the development process it worked fine. The barebones dialog would launch and close as expected. But now that I am close to full functionality, the dialog does not close by the Submit and/or close buttons.

I need to invoke the (Ctrl-Shift I) Dev console tab for the dialog to close. I haven't yet figured out a programmatic way to do this yet. ChangeDetectorRef does not seem to fix this issue.

Not quite sure what code to post here. Hoping that someone has experienced this before and knows a simple setting or two that I need to set straight.

Any help is much appreciated.